GCP-App Engine - Spring Bot Application 404 error
After building maven with command:
clean package appengine:deploy -P cloud-gcp
I got 404 error :
Below are the confgurations used:( I use MySQL with hibernate)
app.yaml
runtime: java11
env_variables:
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp,mysql"
handlers:

url: /.*
script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
instances: 1
spring-cloud-bootstrap.properties:
spring.cloud.appId=murali-401522
application-gcp.properties:
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=
murali-401522:us-central1:myappdb
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=myappdb


application.properties:
spring.application.name=
server.servlet.context-path=/MA
server.port=8080

spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=DEBUG
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
server.servlet.session.timeout=60s
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=60s

#Spring Security
spring.security.user.name=murali
spring.security.user.password=murali

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:///quickstart-db?cloudSqlInstance=murali-401522:us-central1:myappdb&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=quickstart-user&password=&useSSL=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default

#Sending Email
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=muralidharan2973x@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=nazcwlrsezmppwws
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

#Adding this property since it is enabled by default
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=false

URL:https://murali-401512.uc.r.appspot.com/MA/

404 means url not found. It does not have anything to do with your mysql configuration.

Did you try to support the trailing slash? It already solved one of my errors with Springboot and GAE. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-3-url-matching#override-default-configuration

I tried with this, Please explain more.

2024-10-20 13:20:16 default[20241005t183851]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
2024-10-20 13:20:16 default[20241005t183851]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
2024-10-20 13:20:20 default[20241005t183851]  "GET /MA HTTP/1.1" 302
2024-10-20 13:20:20 default[20241005t183851]  "GET /MA/ HTTP/1.1" 404
